# Error while exporting a access recordset in .xlsx

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to export record set "myTableRS" from Access 2010 into .xlsx file via VBA, but its showing the error as " The expression you entered is the wrong datatype for one of its argument". If I access any field value from the record set in msgbox using Msgbox(myTableRS![Field3]) so its working fine. Even when i export Access Table so the below code is working fine but not working for myTableRS record set.

I am using the code :

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
   myTableRS, "D:\MAS.xlsx", True
```

Can anyone tell how to fix it?

---

How do I create a saved query? I have a table from which I want to search a particular record and save that particular record only at the same time of search in xlsx

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx), you will see that table name is a string.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
   "myTableRS", "D:\MAS.xlsx", True
```

This means that you cannot export a recordset using TransferSpreadsheet, however, you can create a saved query and export that.

Create a saved query

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = " & thenumber

If Not IsNull(DLookup( _
    "ExportQuery", "MSysObjects", "[Name]='ExportQuery' AND Type= 5")) Then
    ''Query exists, overwrite the sql permanently
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ExportQuery").SQL = sSQL
Else
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "ExportQuery", sSQL
End If
```

Comment: I believe I have shown how to create a saved query.